# Fundamental questions about Logarithm and finding quadratic roots

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, proof-verification, special-functions

Define: $(e^{iz}+e^{-iz})/2= cos z$ where $z \in \Bbb C $, i.e, the cosine function is defined for complex $z$. Now, is it true that for each $w \in  \Bbb C $ there is $z \in \Bbb C $ such that $cos z = w$?

I claim yes and prove it in the following manner but I have some issues with certain steps in the proof:

Proof:

Let $u=e^{iz}$

then, $cos z = w \implies u^{2}- 2wu+ 1 = 0$

$\implies u=[w \pm \sqrt (w^{2}-1)] \implies  e^{iz}= [w \pm \sqrt (w^{2}-1)]$

$\implies  e^{iz}= [w \pm \sqrt (w^{2}-1)]e^{i2\pi k}, k=0,\pm 1, \pm 2,... $

$\implies log (e^{iz})= log ([w \pm \sqrt (w^{2}-1)]e^{i2\pi k}) $

$\implies z=-i log (w \pm \sqrt (w^{2}-1)]) + 2\pi k$

Now I have two fundamental questions.

1) Is the logarithm of complex numbers defined and allowed as I have done in the proof?

2) Does the quadratic formula for calculating roots still hold good for complex coefficients ($w$ in this case)?

Finally, please suggest a modified proof if something is wrong.